# Add text beside checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

when click the checkbox another modal will pop up for the quantity of the selected value and I check Geda Jumuad and add "2" as quantity value but then the value '2' was put in the beginning of the checboxes . .
 I want to put the quantity value beside the selected checkbox.. please help me.
heres my code

```
<b>Menu: </b>
<br>
<div class="menucontainers" style="background: #fff; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; border-color:#ccccff; width: 400px; height:150px; overflow:auto;">
  <!-- <img src ="../1.jpg" class="img-rounded"> -->

  <ul>
      <?php
                          include ('myConnection.php');

                          $query = "Select * from menu_category order by menu_cat_name";
                          $result = mysql_query($query);
                          while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                              $menucatname = $row['menu_cat_name'];
                              $menucatid = $row['menu_cat_id_inc'];

                        ?>
          <li class="dropdownz" style="border-style: solid;border-color: white; border-bottom: 2px; border-left: 2px; border-right: 2px">
              <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdownz" style="font-size:15px">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i id = "arrow" class="icon-arrow"></i><?php echo "$menucatname"; ?></a>
              <ul id="ddownz-menu" class="dropdownz-menu">
                  <li>
                      <?php
                              $query2 = "Select * from menu where menu_cat_id_inc = '$menucatid' order by menu_name";
                              $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
                              $countme = 0;
                              while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
                                  $menuname = $row2['menu_name'];
                                  $price = $row2['price'];                          
                              if ($countme % 2 == 0)
                              {
                            ?>
                          <div class="col col-md-6">
                              &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                              <input type="checkbox" id="newmenu" name="cbox[]" style="font-size:15px" value="<?php echo $row2['menu_id_inc'];?>">
                              <?php

                                      echo '<span id = "quantity" style = "color:black;"></span>'. " " . "$menuname";
                                  ?>

                          </div>
                          <?php
                              }
                              else
                              {

                              ?>
                              <div class="col col-md-4">
                                  <input type="checkbox" id="newmenu" name="cbox[]" value="<?php echo $row2['menu_id_inc'];?>">

                                  <?php
                                      echo '<span id = "quantity" style = "color:black;"></span>'. " " . "$menuname";
                                  ?>
                              </div>

                              <?php
                              }
                              }
                                  ?>
                  </li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <?php
                          }

                        ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and for javascript. .

```
$("#qtyok").click(function () {
    var id = $("#menuid").val();
    var qty = $("#qtybox").val();
    if (qty != '') {
        $("#loaderz").show();
        $.post("fm_valuemenuload.php", {
                id: id,
                qty: qty

            },
            function (data, status) {
                $("#loaderz").hide();
                $("#modalQty").modal('hide');
                $("#message").html('Added');
                document.getElementById('quantity').innerHTML = qty;
                price += data * qty;
                $("#newprice").val(price.toFixed(2));
                $("#modalSUCCESS").modal('show');
                setTimeout(func1, 3000);

            });
    }
});
```

`

Comment: There's quite a bunch of php code in what you provided. Could you trim down your code to the minimum so we could debug it in jsfiddle?

Comment: I wanna add quantity to the selected checkbox item and put the added quantity beside the selected checkbox value.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your problem but... I think you just got it in the wrong order. Place the span after the $menuname.

Instead of

`echo '<span id = "quantity" style = "color:black;"></span>'. " " . "$menuname";`

Do

`echo "$menuname".' <span id = "quantity" style = "color:black;"></span>';`

You also must assign unique ids to your spans. Although your checkboxes are dynamic, you can for example retrieve the value of those checkboxes and append it to 'quantity'. You will have ids 'quantity1', 'quantity2', 'quantity3' produced. Change the previous line of code to

```
echo "$menuname".' <span id = "quantity'.$row2['menu_id_inc'].'" style = "color:black;"></span>';
```

You will also have to do something similar in your javascript. Retrieve the checkbox value number in a javascript variable, and append it to 'quantity' here

```
document.getElementById('quantity' + value).innerHTML = qty;
```

Comment: actually it worked but everytime i checked another checkbox the quantity i added will put to the first checkbox value.

Comment: Now that is a problem with the javascript code. I'm looking into it.

Comment: All of your quantity spans have the id 'quantity'. It is better to have an unique id for common elements to separate them. `document.getElementById('quantity')` retrieves the first quantity span, beside the first checkbox, because all of your quantity spans share the same id. I will be back with some code in a few minutes.

Comment: but my checkbox is dynamic i can't assign them a unique id.

Comment: You actually can. I'm updating my answer with how.

Comment: There. By appending the values of your checkboxes to the quantity ids, you can get uniques ids for your quantity spans.